# 'Permission denied' error when I tried to use getUserMedia in teams desktop popup window

Tags: microsoft-teams

I use `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` to open our app(the sample code is https://github.com/Wajeed-msft/DevicePermissionsDemo/blob/master/DevicePermissionsDemo/Pages/Index.cshtml).

```js
microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
  url: <our app's url, use https policy>,
  width: 300,
  height: 520,
})
```

And when I try to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })` to request user media permission, it always returns error "DOMException: Permission denied". Error is page shows

[image]

according to doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=desktop

my teams app already get the permission:
[image]

Same is chrome settings in chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%3A443
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please take a look at following [device permission sample](https://github.com/Wajeed-msft/DevicePermissionsDemo/blob/master/DevicePermissionsDemo/Pages/Index.cshtml) code which have getUserMedia() device permissions implemented for Tab.

Comment: Thanks, I tried. It shows Error 'Error name: NotAllowedError; Error message: Permission denied; Error constraintName: undefined'

Comment: Hi @joyvince, Could you please get permissions from your IT Admin.

Comment: Hi @Jagadeesh-MSFT, I  think I could get the permissions because I can get the microphone permissions on the Personal Tab page, I just cannot get the permissions in the popup window. Or how could I check if I can get permissions？